# How to publish sonarqube scanned reports to multiple SonarQube Instances..?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5, sonarlint-vs

I have two SonarQube Instances one is 6.1 Developers Edition and the other one is 6.7 LTS version.
I want to publish the scanned results to two Sonar Instances.
How can i achieve this..?

Regards,
Sandeep